# Search function in java.util.stack in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using a java.util.Stack class in Matlab.

I am pushing some points ([x,y]) into it to store them, but when I want to search for one of them using `list.search(point)` it always returns `-1`, even if the point it's inside!

Some code showing the problem:

```
list = java.util.Stack();
list.push([1, 2]);
list.push([2, 3]);
list.push([3, 4]);
ind = list.search([2,3]);
```

The value return by `list.search([2,3])` is `-1`. Why?

Do you know any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post some code? Seeing what you've done for creating the list, adding a few points and trying to search one would help a lot...

Comment: @Bentoy13 Edited to show the problem ;)

Comment: I think `search` actually compares the addresses of the objects, not applying a specific type-dependant comparator. So best way is either to loop over each element, or better use normal matlab array for that ...